# Why is ColdFusion adding whitespace when I call a function in cfoutput?

Tags: coldfusion, whitespace

If I do something like this in ColdFusion:

```
<cfoutput>foo="#foo()#"</cfoutput>
```

The resulting HTML has a space in front of it:

```
foo=" BAR"
```

However, if it is not a function call it works fine, i.e.:

```
<cfset fooOut=foo() />
<cfoutput>foo="#fooOut#"</cfoutput>
```

Gives this output:

```
foo="BAR"
```

Where is this extra space coming from and is there anything I can do about it?

---

**Edit** To clarify, the space is not in the value returned by my `foo` function:

```
<cffunction name="foo" access="public" returntype="string">
  <cfreturn "BAR" />
</cffunction>
```

But I've also found that this doesn't happen with built-in functions, i.e.:

```
<cfoutput>"#UCase("bar")#"</cfoutput>
```

Prints:

```
"BAR"
```

However, it does happen if I pass the output of my function to the built-in function (this part makes no sense to me). i.e.:

```
<cfoutput>"#UCase(foo())#"</cfoutput>
```

Prints:

```
" BAR"
```

Comment: This is definitely a hack and doesn't answer your question, but have you tried using the Trim() function to remove the whitespace?

Comment: @dbyrne: i tried that, but the value returned by foo() doesn't have a space to begin with, so the trim does nothing, and then the result of trim gets a space added to it, just like the result of foo()

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Make sure you have output attribute defined as false.

```
<cfcomponent output="false">

  <cffunction name="foo" access="public" returntype="string" output="false">
    <cfreturn "BAR">
  </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Or, do it in cfscript style, and no extra space will be introduced.

```
function foo()
{
  return "BAR";
}
```

Comment: Does anyone know why the whitespace char gets added?